Is it safe to pass function pointer to message handler via lParam?
Some code:
LRESULT CScopeFrame::OnDATACallback(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::function<void()>* callbackPtr = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(lParam);

    if (callbackPtr && *callbackPtr)
    {
        (*callbackPtr)();
    }

    return 0;
}

    void sendCallbackMessage(CWnd* pWnd) const
    {
        if (callBackType == CALLMESSAGE && callbackNoParam)
        {
            if (pWnd != nullptr)
            {
                // Post the callback function address via LPARAM
                pWnd->PostMessage(WM_USER_ON_DATA_CALLBACK, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&callbackNoParam));
            }
        }
    }

    void sendCallbackMessage() const
    {
        if (callBackType == CALLMESSAGE && callbackNoParam)
        {
            CWnd* pWnd = AfxGetMainWnd();  // Get the main window pointer
            if (pWnd != nullptr)
            {
                // Post the callback function address via LPARAM
                pWnd->PostMessage(WM_USER_ON_DATA_CALLBACK, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&callbackNoParam));
            }
        }
    }

    void triggerSendMessage() const
    {
        if (asyncCallBack)
        {
            CWnd* pWnd = AfxGetMainWnd();  // Get the main window pointer
            //std::sync should use system threead pool minimazing overhead.
            std::async(std::launch::async, [this, pWnd]()
                {
                    sendCallbackMessage(pWnd);
                });
        }
        else
        {
            sendCallbackMessage();
        }
    };

where
std::function<void()> callbackNoParam;

Function to call is UI class method called via lambda:
hwData->addOrGetData<int>(sensorNames::BATTERY, [this]() {this->Update(); }, DATA<int>::CALLMESSAGE, true);

    template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<DATA<T>> addOrGetData(const std::string& name,
        std::function<void()> callback,
        typename DATA<T>::CALLBACKTYPE callBackType = DATA<T>::CALLONCHANGE,
        bool asyncCallBack = true)

This method adds callback to the callback vector. Is this lambda safe?
It works as expected but my question is - is it safe and correct?
I have a limited experience (I did not touch MFC and
Windows for 15years) and C++ is not the language I am proficient with.

Yes. LPARAM is used to pass pointers all the time. A function pointer is fine. Keep in mind, though, that a method pointer is a different beast. If you need that, pass a pointer to the object, then use that object to invoke the function.

@Dúthomhas I pass pointer to lambda (at least I think) - as I said I am not strong in c++

while it is not illegal, i am genuinely worried about the lifetime of the object whose address was sent, you are mentioning a vector ... pointers to objects in vectors are not safe ... consider adding it to a thread-safe map instead and send some identifier instead, then when the callback happens use the identifier to search for the object in the map, you either find it or you don't, either way your app doesn't crash.

@AhmedAEK It is actually the map

You are not passing a function pointer, you are passing an object pointer to a std::function object.  Which is perfectly fine, as long as that object remains valid until after the message handler is done using it.

also std::async is blocking if you ignore its return ... the destructor of its return is blocking, PostMessage is already asynchronous, it only post the message to be received in the future, you don't need std::async

@AhmedAEK a very good point

Yes as long as it is sent and not posted and return.

On Windows using Visual C++, yes, that is supported, see here. It is non-standard though.

@Axalo There aren't any function pointers in the question.

@IInspectable I'm just answering the question in the title. It is after all how people will find this question.

A function pointer is not a lambda, however, they are similar. Lambdas capture state, be t

@Kit10 A lambda is an object. It may capture state, in the sense that it can copy values or create references. The issue at hand is whether or not either the object or any object captured by reference goes out of scope before the callback is invoked.

For your purpose you may need two pointers: WPARAM (for this pointer) and LPARAM for the function pointer.

It's not clear what the lifetime of callbackNoParam is. Is it a global variable? A member variable? A local variable? It's probably not a global variable or a member of CScopeFrame-- if it were, then you could just use it from CScopeFrame::OnDATACallback directly. So it's a local variable? You need to keep that local variable alive until the posted message is processed.

@RaymondChen it is a member of Singelton class - its lifetime is the same as of the program

Then maybe you don't need to put it in the posted message at all. Just CScopeFrame::OnDATACallback access the singleton to get the function pointer.

@RaymondChen it is posted from the singleton method which can called from not UI thread.

That isn't really relevant which thread posts the message. Why can't you do LRESULT LRESULT CScopeFrame::OnDATACallback(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { GetSingleton()->callbackNoParam(); return 0; }?

@RaymondChen - as some callbacks modify UI, so they have to be from the same UI thread

Right, you post the message to the UI thread. But the message handler can just access the callbackNoParam member. (All you're doing is passing a pointer to callbackNoParam in the LPARAM, which is redundant since you already know its address: It's GetSingleton()->callbackNoParam!

No, this looks bad.
In C++ you must understand the lifetime of all references and pointed to things.
PostMessage is async (it does not evaluate during the call), so your pointer may or may not be valid when the message is processed.
How actually to do this correctly would require more information than you have shared. It probably requires more background knowledge than you have, as you are referring to a std function as a lambda (or vice versa).
Imagine someone asking how to order a hamburger, but they keep on calling clothing "automobiles" and assuming shirts can drive on highways. The gap is too large.

Your language at the end is not kind. It would be better to suggest an alternative than to mistreat the OP for perceived misunderstandings.
